# iPhone and ASIHTTPRequest - Unable to start HTTP connection

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

I am using the ASIHTTPRequest class in order to communicate with a web service and get a response. This is how I send a request to the server

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@verifyLogin.json", serverUrl];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8"];
NSDictionary* data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:emailId, @"username", pwd, @"password", nil];
[request appendPostData: [[data JSONFragment] dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFinishSelector: @selector(gotLoginResponse:)];
[request setDidFailSelector: @selector(loginRequestFailed:)];

[networkQueue addOperation: request];
[networkQueue go];
```

The control immediately goes to the error routine and the error description and domain are

**Unable to start HTTP connection** and **ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain**

I can get the same request to work via a desktop tool for checking HTTP requests so I know the settings are all correct.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here while sending the request?

Thanks.

Comment: in your first line it says "%verifyLogin.json". Shouldn't that be; "%@verifyLogin.json" ????

Comment: I have the same issue, any luck?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I commented earlier;

> in your first line it says
>   "%verifyLogin.json". Shouldn't that
>   be; "%@verifyLogin.json" ????

Answer (score 2):

For me I forgot to add http:// as i was testing locally. But after adding http it ran successfully

Comment: the same case here :D

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the status code of the request when it fails? I recently dealt with a JSON user authentication issue with ASI-HTTP-Request where the first request would always fail with Status Code 0 and some sort of underlying network connection failure (as if it wasn't connected to the internet, but clearly was).

I was able to solve it by setting that particular request to not attempt to use a persistent connection.

So try that first!